# How to automatically delete all cookies set by a particular site?

Tags: google-chrome

Even **after** I logout, Facebook still sets 9 cookies, 2 out of those 9 are set to expire 2 years ahead, while the rest expire when I close the browser. I don't like that. I'm using chrome. When I click logout, I want it to clear every cookie belonging to Facebook? How can I achieve this with chrome?

Comment: I just received an email from Mozilla today promoting how to do that in Firefox. Maybe you should switch browswer ;)

Comment: Feel like sharing that information?

Comment: @billc.cn Please share!

Comment: [How do I remove a single website from my history?](http://goo.gl/YVQ4y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using "Incognito Mode" (http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95464) in Google Chrome. All cookies will be deleted when ending the incognito session that way.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences, Click 'Under the Hood', Click on 'Content Settings', check the checkbox for 'Clear cookies and other site and plug-in data when I quit my browser'
You'll have to close Chrome after logout though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER). CCleaner is a popular app that deletes temporary files, cookies, browser histories and other junk from your computer. It has an option to whitelist cookies. CCleaner will look in every browser and remove all cookies NOT on this whitelist. I find this feature very useful because my whitelist only includes websites I'm normally logged into (Google, SuperUser, reddit et al).

Comment: He wants it to do it automatically when he logs out, not have to run another program to do it.